# Error while calling another python file in wxGUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am new to wxPython.I have made a simple GUI that contains a button and by pressing that button i am calling another .py file...But i am getting error using the command:

top_block.start()

The error is:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'start'

The code is as shown.I am using python 2.7.3.Any improvements in the code are also welcome.

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, title="The Main Frame")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="",
                pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize,
                style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,
                name="MyFrame"):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title,
            pos, size, style, name)
        # Attributes
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        self.button3=wx.Button(self, -1, ' Execute ', wx.Point(235, 90),
                 wx.DefaultSize)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Execute,self.button3)


        def Execute(self,event):
            import top_block
            top_block.start()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I would assume that module top_block has no method start ...

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `start` method in `top_block` it needs to be a top level method, otherwise if there is a class in `top_block.py` called `top_block` that has a method start you need either `top_block.top_block.start()` or change your import to `from top_block import top_block` so as to reference the method of the object.